# Add Google black navbar to website

Tags: navbar

Is there a way to add [the black Google navbar](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Fs0BwTW_I14/Tw69Xyjmx6I/AAAAAAABD9I/UceEWXiUdc8/s640/google-old-ui.png) to my website? Is there a snippet somewhere that I can use?

Comment: What do you exactly want? Do you want a bar similar to the Google one with, let's say, custom content? That exact bar? With the [logged] users' options?

Comment: ultraklon -> I want that exact bar and if possible, it should work just like the one on google does.